# Can having low entropy cause an HTTPS server to be slower?

Tags: random, https

We are very low on entropy (HW: Lenovo ThinkCentre M58, OS: Ubuntu 12.04, not a VM, SW: HTTPS Apache server):

```
root@server:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
417
root@server:~#
```

**Question**: Could this affect the performance of our HTTPS server or OpenSSH?

Comment: To preempt your next question: take a look at `rngd` or `haveged`, which both aim to periodically top up entropy.

Comment: @pepite, short answer is no and as far as I understand this. As @Ulrich Schwarz mentioned, you can test it easily and fast with HArdware Volatile Entropy Gathering and Expansion (Havege). Just install the daemon via `apt-get install haveged`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think your entropy is at a low enough level just yet. I recall 100-200 being the "start to worry" threshold. If you search the web, just avoid doing this:

```
DO NOT DO THIS: rngd -r /dev/urandom
```

For reference on why not do do that, [here is a lwn article](https://lwn.net/Articles/525459/).

You mention that you have HW. You could generate some entropy (keyboard/mouse is best, failing that, network and disk (large finds, counting, etc, are next.). Finally there is supposed to be a daemon called haveged that generates entropy. I have not researched it.

Answer (score -1):

It may block while generating SSL/TLS or block ciphers until the available entropy would recover. Most applications will either use its own random seed or use `/dev/urandom` to avoid blocking providing a decrease in the quality of randomness, those affecting the integrity of security. At the end it's a question of balance between availability vs. security.

Comment: No. I haven't checked for Apache httpd specifically, but a reasonable application will not use `/dev/random` routinely. A reasonable application will in fact not use `/dev/random`, only `/dev/urandom`, which [is perfectly fine for security](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/) except in specific scenarios involving freshly-booted devices. And even an application that used `/dev/random` would only fail when it starts, after that it should use its own internal PRNG.

Comment: My bad. I supposed what lot of other people suppose! Thanks for keeping me updated on this one.